# Python program freezes and closes when entering an input?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, anaconda, freeze

I am currently writing a program which graphs a polynomial and shades the area under the curve between two endpoints using Simpson's 3/8th's rule, and then prints that info on the graph. Currently, the program works properly for one polynomial ("(x - 3) * (x - 5) * (x - 7) + 85") between two endpoints (2 and 9). However, when attempting to have the program accept an input for either the polynomial or either endpoint using the input command, the program freezes and crashes without constructing a graph. This occurs even if the current numbers are re-entered. Below is the code:

Here is the base of the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
```

Here I define the polynomial to be func(x)

```
def func(x):
    return (x - 3) * (x - 5) * (x - 7) + 85
```

Here I define the function with which to calculate area under the curve using Simpson's rule

```
def simpson(function, a, b, n):
    """Approximates the definite integral of f from a to b by the
    composite Simpson's rule, using n subintervals (with n even)"""

    if n % 2:
        raise ValueError("n must be even (received n=%d)" % n)

    h = (b - a) / n #The first section of Simpson's 3/8ths rule
    s = function(a) + function(b) #The addition of functions over an interval

    for i in range(1, n, 2):
        s += 4 * function(a + i * h)
    for i in range(2, n-1, 2):
        s += 2 * function(a + i * h)

    return(s * h / 3)
```

Here I define the endpoints between which to integrate

```
a, b = 2, 9  # integral limits
```

Here are a few more definitions for convenience

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10) #Generates 100 points evenly spaced between 0 and 10
y = func(x) #Just defines y to be f(x) so its ez later on

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x, y, 'r', linewidth=2)
plt.ylim(ymin=0)

final_integral = simpson(lambda t:func(t), a, b, 100000)
```

Here I construct the shaded region

```
# Make the shaded region
ix = np.linspace(a, b)
iy = func(ix)
verts = [(a, 0)] + list(zip(ix, iy)) + [(b, 0)]
poly = Polygon(verts, facecolor='0.9', edgecolor='0.5')
ax.add_patch(poly)
```

Here I print the integral notation on the graph

```
plt.text(0.5 * (a + b), 30, r"$\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm{d}x$",
     horizontalalignment='center', fontsize=20)
```

Here I print the area under the curve as calculated by simpson's 3/8ths rule on the graph

```
ax.text(0.25, 135, r"Using Simpson's 3/8ths rule, the area under the curve is: ", fontsize=20) #r denotes a raw string
ax.text(0.25, 114, final_integral , fontsize=20) #prints the value of the 
integral defined using simpson's 3/8ths prior
```

Here I finish constructing the graph

```
plt.figtext(0.9, 0.05, '$x$')
plt.figtext(0.1, 0.9, '$y$')

ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False) #no dashes on axis
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False) 
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')

ax.set_xticks((a, b))
ax.set_xticklabels(('$a$', '$b$'))
ax.set_yticks([])

plt.show()
```

Yet, when I change the line where the endpoints are defined to read 'a, b = int(input("enter your endpoints in the format 2,9"))  # integral limits', the program [errors out as shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpHLY.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated. I'm struggling to understand the dilemma, so I appoligize for not providing more info.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug in the run-time system, in that it doesn't give you an error message.  A crash is rarely an acceptable response.

I suspect that the proximate cause is your invalid input conversion: **int** takes a string argument with a single integer represented.  When you try to assign this to *two* variables, you *should* get a message telling you that there aren't enough values to unpack ... but first, you'll get a ValueError for trying to turn a string such as "2,9" into a single integer.

Try this, instead:

```
str_in = input("enter your endpoints in the format 2,9")  # integral limits
fields = str_in.split(',')
a, b = [int(i) for i in fields]
```

You can add error-checking or collapse this to a single line -- but I expect that you can see the needed processing now.